# Calculate the power of a test with an unknown $\mu$

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

> In order to prevent damages to the wind turbines, the windspeed is monitored every 5 seconds, and
>   if it is determined that the variance of the windspeed is high the turbine switches off to a safe mode.
>
> Let $X_1, . . . , X_{12}$ be independent random variables representing the measurements made in a one minute period (in km/h). We can assume these are normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, both unknown. At every minute the following hypothesis test is performed:
>   $\left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
> H_0: \sigma = 75 km/h\\
> H_A: \sigma \geq 75 km/h
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $
>
> The turbine is programmed to stop if $S ≥ 83.7km/h$ (this is the critical region of the test), where S
>   is the sample standard deviation
>
> Suppose that $\sigma = 110km/h$. Is it true that the power of the test in this situation is larger than $0.75$?

The power of a test is the probability that the null hypothesis is rejected when it is false. So what is the probability that $S \geq 83.7$, given that $\sigma \geq 75$, and in this case $\sigma=110$.
$$Power=P(S \geq 83.7 | \sigma=110)$$

I don't know how to solve this. I thought about standardizing, but $\mu$ is unknown so I don't think that's going to work.

Comment: It is not necessary to know $\mu$ in order to do this test on $\sigma^2.$ The computation of the sample variance $S^2$ uses the estimate $\bar X$ of $\mu.$ Then you have $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n-1).$ Try using that relationship to find $P(S\ge 83.7|\sigma=110),$ and edit your result into your Question. Then maybe one of us can check your work.

Comment: It looks as if you're not testing at the 5% level of significance. What level?

Answer (score 1):

*Comment* continued:

My guess is that you are expected to obtain an analytic solution using the
chi-squared distribution according to the relationship in my earlier comment.
However, the following simulation in R provides a pretty good hint that
the answer to the main question is that the power is indeed greater than $0.75.$

```
set.seed(1213);  m = 10^5; n = 12;  sg = 110;  mu = 100
s = replicate(m, sd(rnorm(n, mu, sg)))
mean(s > 83.7)
[1] 0.84682
```

*Note:* In the simulation it is crucial to have $\sigma = 110$ (code `sg = 110`).
It is also necessary to have *some* value of $\mu$ in order to do the
simulation. But notice that the result doesn't depend on what you pick. (For
normal data, $\bar X$ and $S^2$ are *independent* random variables.)

```
  set.seed(1213);  m = 10^5; n = 12;  sg = 110;  mu = 200   # value of mu irrelevant
  s = replicate(m, sd(rnorm(n, mu, sg)))
  mean(s > 83.7)
  [1] 0.84682
```

If you knew the value of $\mu$ then the natural estimate of $\sigma^2$ would
be $V = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2$ and you would have
$\frac{nV}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n).$ This is easy to show. But some
beginning students are surprised that the corresponding quantity involving
$S^2$ has $n-1$ degrees of freedom, which is a little more difficult to prove.

By making a histogram of the simulated values (first simulation) of $Q = 11S^2/\sigma^2$ one can make the
graph below illustrating that $\mathsf{Chisq}(11)$ is the correct distribution
and $\mathsf{Chisq}(12)$ is not.

[image]